# For loop for adding their weights

Tags: python, for-loop

I need help in creating a for loop for accumulating their weights in a list.

this is my code

```
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) == 4:
        if len(receiver) == 4:
            # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
            if host[0] in alphabet and host[1] in alphabet and host[2] in alphabet and host[3] in alphabet:
                if receiver[0] in alphabet and receiver[1] in alphabet and receiver[2] in alphabet and receiver[3] in alphabet:
                    final_chain = [host]
                    receiver_index_1 = alphabet.index(receiver[0])
                    # Call for_loop_sort for each position in the host and receiver
                    chain_1 = for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_1) + host[1:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_1)
                    receiver_index_2 = alphabet.index(receiver[1])
                    chain_2 = receiver[0] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_2) + host[2:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_2)
                    receiver_index_3 = alphabet.index(receiver[2])
                    chain_3 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_3) + host[3:]
                    final_chain.append(chain_3)
                    receiver_index_4 = alphabet.index(receiver[3])
                    chain_4 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + receiver[2] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_4)
                    final_chain.append(chain_4)
                    return final_chain
                else:
                    return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
            else:
                return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
        else:
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    else:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."

def for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index):
    # Iterate through the alphabet list
    for index in range(len(alphabet)):
        # Check if the current index matches the receiver_index
        if index == receiver_index:
            return alphabet[index]

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]

# Process each receiver and print the resulting chain
for receiver in receivers:
    result = agent(host, receiver)
    chain_1, chain_2, chain_3, chain_4 = result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]
    
    # Assign weights to chain_1, chain_2, chain_3, and chain_4
    chain_1_weight = 40
    chain_2_weight = 30
    chain_3_weight = 20
    chain_4_weight = 10

    cweights = {1:40, 2:30, 3:20, 4:10}
    
    # Check if the chain transformations exist in other final_chains and add their weights
    if chain_1 in result[2:]:
        chain_1_weight += chain_1_weight
    if chain_2 in result[3:]:
        chain_2_weight += chain_2_weight
    if chain_3 in result[4:]:
        chain_3_weight += chain_3_weight
    if chain_4 in result[5:]:
        chain_4_weight += chain_4_weight
    
    print(f"{chain_1}: {chain_1_weight} -> {chain_2}: {chain_2_weight} -> {chain_3}: {chain_3_weight} -> {chain_4}: {chain_4_weight}")
```

The output was this

```
MORE: 40 -> MBRE: 30 -> MBIE: 20 -> MBID: 10
BORE: 40 -> BRRE: 30 -> BRKE: 20 -> BRKS: 10
JORE: 40 -> JKRE: 30 -> JKIE: 20 -> JKIC: 10
MORE: 40 -> MRRE: 60 -> MRRE: 20 -> MRRY: 10
BORE: 40 -> BTRE: 30 -> BTLE: 20 -> BTLR: 10
AORE: 40 -> ADRE: 30 -> ADBE: 20 -> ADBY: 10
DORE: 40 -> DRRE: 30 -> DRNE: 20 -> DRNT: 10
IORE: 40 -> IRRE: 30 -> IRVE: 20 -> IRVN: 10
HORE: 40 -> HRRE: 30 -> HRDE: 20 -> HRDN: 10
DORE: 40 -> DNRE: 30 -> DNCE: 20 -> DNCN: 10
BORE: 40 -> BRRE: 30 -> BRNE: 20 -> BRNT: 10
PORE: 40 -> PARE: 30 -> PAUE: 20 -> PAUL: 10
WORE: 40 -> WRRE: 30 -> WRTE: 20 -> WRTH: 10
JORE: 40 -> JNRE: 30 -> JNSE: 20 -> JNSN: 10
LORE: 40 -> LLRE: 60 -> LLRE: 20 -> LLRD: 10
BORE: 40 -> BIRE: 60 -> BIRE: 20 -> BIRD: 10
JORE: 40 -> JRRE: 30 -> JRDE: 20 -> JRDN: 10
PORE: 40 -> PIRE: 30 -> PIPE: 20 -> PIPN: 10
EORE: 40 -> EWRE: 30 -> EWNE: 20 -> EWNG: 10
BORE: 40 -> BRRE: 30 -> BRKE: 20 -> BRKL: 10
OORE: 40 -> OLRE: 30 -> OLJE: 20 -> OLJW: 10
CORE: 40 -> CRRE: 60 -> CRRE: 20 -> CRRY: 10
TORE: 40 -> TMRE: 30 -> TMPE: 20 -> TMPS: 10
TORE: 40 -> TTRE: 30 -> TTUE: 20 -> TTUM: 10
GORE: 40 -> GRRE: 30 -> GRNE: 20 -> GRNT: 10
```

But I want to create a for loop for the weights. If the chains exist in the same position on other paths, their weights will be added by how many it exists. Then if the chains exist in different positions except in their current positions, then their weights will be added by adding their fixed weight and the weight of the current position.

The weights of each chain are 40, 30, 20, and 10 respectively as I assigned them in the code.

The `result[0]` is the host so it should not be included. However, the sorted chain of a specific receiver exists in the final chain, so the weight will be added to 40.

So the output will be something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

not sure what this is aside from maybe you are an NBA fan. added two data collectors in the first `for` loop and another `for` loop to display the results.

```py
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

def agent(host, receiver):
    # Check the length of host and receiver
    if len(host) != 4:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    if len(receiver) != 4:
        return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have 4 capital letters."
    # Check if host and receiver have valid IDs (capital letters)
    # if host[0] in alphabet and host[1] in alphabet and host[2] in alphabet and host[3] in alphabet:
    if all(h in alphabet for h in host):
        # if receiver[0] in alphabet and receiver[1] in alphabet and receiver[2] in alphabet and receiver[3] in alphabet:
        if all(r in alphabet for r in receiver):
            final_chain = [host]
            receiver_index_1 = alphabet.index(receiver[0])
            # Call for_loop_sort for each position in the host and receiver
            chain_1 = for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_1) + host[1:]
            final_chain.append(chain_1)
            receiver_index_2 = alphabet.index(receiver[1])
            chain_2 = receiver[0] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_2) + host[2:]
            final_chain.append(chain_2)
            receiver_index_3 = alphabet.index(receiver[2])
            chain_3 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_3) + host[3:]
            final_chain.append(chain_3)
            receiver_index_4 = alphabet.index(receiver[3])
            chain_4 = receiver[0] + receiver[1] + receiver[2] + for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index_4)
            final_chain.append(chain_4)
            return final_chain
        else:
            return "Error, receiver agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"
    else:
        return "Error, host agent has an invalid ID; agent should only have capital letters"

def for_loop_sort(host, receiver, receiver_index):
    # Iterate through the alphabet list
    for index in range(len(alphabet)):
        # Check if the current index matches the receiver_index
        if index == receiver_index:
            return alphabet[index]

host = "CORE"
receivers = ["MBID", "BRKS", "JKIC", "MRRY", "BTLR",
             "ADBY", "DRNT", "IRVN", "HRDN", "DNCN",
             "BRNT", "PAUL", "WRTH", "JNSN", "LLRD",
             "BIRD", "JRDN", "PIPN", "EWNG", "BRKL",
             "OLJW", "CRRY", "TMPS", "TTUM", "GRNT"]
chains = {'chain_1': {}, 'chain_2': {}, 'chain_3': {}, 'chain_4': {}}
results = []

# Process each receiver and print the resulting chain
for receiver in receivers:
    result = agent(host, receiver)
    results.append(result[1:5])
    chain_1, chain_2, chain_3, chain_4 = result[1:5] # result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]
    
    # Assign weights to chain_1, chain_2, chain_3, and chain_4
    chain_1_weight = chains['chain_1'].get(chain_1, 0) + 40
    chain_2_weight = chains['chain_2'].get(chain_2, 0) + 30
    chain_3_weight = chains['chain_3'].get(chain_3, 0) + 20
    chain_4_weight = chains['chain_4'].get(chain_4, 0) + 10

    # cweights = {1:40, 2:30, 3:20, 4:10}
    
    # Check if the chain transformations exist in other final_chains and add their weights
    if chain_1 in result[2:]:
        chain_1_weight += 40
    if chain_2 in result[3:]:
        chain_2_weight += 30
    if chain_3 in result[4:]:
        chain_3_weight += 20
    if chain_4 in result[5:]:
        chain_4_weight += 10
    
    chains['chain_1'].update({chain_1: chain_1_weight})
    chains['chain_2'].update({chain_2: chain_2_weight})
    chains['chain_3'].update({chain_3: chain_3_weight})
    chains['chain_4'].update({chain_4: chain_4_weight})
    # print(f"{chain_1}: {chain_1_weight} -> {chain_2}: {chain_2_weight} -> {chain_3}: {chain_3_weight} -> {chain_4}: {chain_4_weight}")

for c1, c2, c3, c4 in results:
    chain_1, chain_1_weight = c1, chains['chain_1'].get(c1)
    chain_2, chain_2_weight = c2, chains['chain_2'].get(c2)
    chain_3, chain_3_weight = c3, chains['chain_3'].get(c3)
    chain_4, chain_4_weight = c4, chains['chain_4'].get(c4)
    print(f"{chain_1}: {chain_1_weight} -> {chain_2}: {chain_2_weight} -> "
          f"{chain_3}: {chain_3_weight} -> {chain_4}: {chain_4_weight}    ")
```